# Auto add into user group

Tags: groups

I created a three group and three organization  g1,g2,g3,o1,o2,o3 respectively.
I also created a 3 drupal role og1, og2, og3.I assigned these three groups to three user drupal role.I logged in by uesr1 assigned a og1 group. When I am creating a new individual it must add into default group i.e. in g1 group but it is not happening. 
My scenario is that when I will create a new individual it must have a default group.
[image]
If I add new Individual, it must auto choose a defualt group.

Comment: This doesn't appear to involve CiviCRM.  Is this purely a Drupal question?

Comment: Dipak - if you are specifically referring to Organic Groups then pls clarify in your question

Comment: No. I am not using any Organic group. Please refer a image

Comment: In my scenario OG means organization group (og1,og2...).These are just a drupal role.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - it confused several of us

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be using CiviGroup Roles Sync

You should check the documentation here

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/group-roles/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [civirules](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/) and see if you can set up a rule so that New Individual gets added to a Group.

Comment: I tried that also but my scenario is different. If I logged in by **user1** which is connected to **group1** and if he add new individual contact then that contact must goes in **group1**. If I logged in by **user2** which is connected to **group2** and if he add new  individual contact then that contact must goes in **group2**.

Comment: 1/ if you used multisite and user1 only logged in via domain1 then the new contact would be added to group1

Comment: 2/ if you used webforms then user1 could use a form that only role1 has access to which which adds new users to group1